# Black Borders on Reference Images

Tags: image

I'm getting black borders on all the reference images I add and it's making things difficult to work with. Anyone know how I can get rid of them?

[image]

Comment: This is v.2.80.

Comment: I don't know if you can get rid of the line. A solution could be to use your picture as an Image Texture on a plane and use the alpha channel as a factor for transparency.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative approach, you could use file import and select "import image as planes" instead of drag & drop.

[image: Comparison showing image planes can render without borders]

Comment: Hello and welcome to the site! Thank you for contributing! I've taken the liberty of editing and adding a screenshot to your answer; if you disagree with my edits please feel free to [roll them back and/or make additional edits of your own](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/editing). Happy StackExchanging <3